# AutoHotKey - Declaring global array does not work

Tags: arrays, insert, global, autohotkey

```
; Give user the opportunity to choose his own hotkey
Gui, Add, Hotkey, x21 y234 w240 h30 vPanicKey gRunPanicKey,^F12

global myList := ["foo"]

RunPanicKey:
    if(PanicKey != "") { ; Make sure the hotkey chosen by the user isn't empty.
        myList.Insert("bar") ; Insert new string into the array.
        myList2 := myList[2] ; Get 2nd index value and store it in myList2
        MsgBox,0,My Array, The 2nd value of myList is: %myList2%
    }
return
```

It appears that `myList.Insert()` does not work here, because the script cannot find the array, therefore `myList2` is empty. But how come? I thought I made the array global?

Comment: afaik, in AHK you dont need to declare a variable as global except within a function

Comment: also, I dont understand your problem. I ran your program (added `gui show`). every time I enter a key, a msgbox correctly says `the 2nd value is bar`, because that's what's being assigned

Comment: I'm using AutoHotkey 1.1.22.02 and it doesn't work for me. It just says `The 2nd value of myList is: `..

Comment: you should post  the complete source code then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GuiClose:
    ExitApp
return

global myList := ["foo"]
```

As seen from your comment, the problem lies not within the `global` keyword (which you actually do not need at all here). The reason your program is not working is that `return` statement. *Everything after the first return in a script does **not** get executed automatically on script start.* See https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto for details. So, simply move the variable initialization at the very beginning of your file.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really didn't know that.. :*